# Could you suggest me the best way to store this type of data! [ JAVA ]

Tags: java

[image: Different Sets of Palindromes]

Look at the very first column of the attached picture - I need a way to store pairs in Java in an array, but sometimes I have to store 2(at most) pairs at the same position. I've been thinking of making an array of arraylist but this seems a bit too much for me, could you be so kind to suggest me something more easy to implement?

Comment: Why not simply create a new class `Pair` with fields `first` and `second` or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the two simplest options would be an array of arrays or even two arrays depending on how you will need to manage your data.

Additionally, you can use a Pair class for modeling your pairs.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel instead of using java's provided `Pair` class?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Andrevin. There is not a Pair class in the standard Java (8) API, though I think in other versions there is. I am editing the answer to not explicitly mention Pair to be programmed by the developer.

Comment: @airos My mistake, I was thinking `javafx` fell under the standard API. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @s_arabov if you found my answer useful, please mark your question as answered by accepting my answer.